# Sox in subprocess not creating output file

Tags: python, sox

I am writing a Python script to mix multiple audio files into one combined file. I am using the Sox command within a subprocess call; however, it is not creating a mixed output file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
subprocess.call('sox -m %s %s' % (' '.join(audios), audio_file.mp3), shell=True)
```

`audios` is a list of the mp3 files (written as a full path) that I have (e.g. `"./Files/Music/a.mp3"`), and `audio_file.mp3` is the mixed audio file I wish to create. I have included the line `!pip install sox` at the top of the script.

Comment: Putting `!pip install sox` at the top of a (Python) script will **not** install it.

Comment: So you have a *Python* object named `audio_file`, that has an attribute named `mp3`?  That looks like it should have been a quoted string instead.

Comment: always try to post a **minimal example reproducing your problem**.

Please post also always the error messages, that you get on the console.

If you call a subprocess from python, then try to call the command yourself from the command line and see what happens.
If you can't get it working from the command line don't even bother trying from python.